# Java ArrayList argument giving <Identifier> expected

Tags: java, arraylist, compiler-errors, arguments

Apparently, whenever I try to compile this code in Java, it keeps telling me  expected at the 4th line on this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Sorts {
    public static void sort(ArrayList objects, Comparator<ZipInfo>) {
    }
}
```

As you can see, it it taking an ArrayList of objects as the first argument to this method. Also, ZipInfo is a class that implements Comparator.
Even if I modify the argument to say "ArrayList objects" it will still claim there is no identifier.
Is there any flaw in this code that would cause it to give this error?

Comment: Argument name is missing. `Comparator<ZipInfo> zipInfoComparator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Comparator argument missing name. Add a name to it.

```
public static void sort(ArrayList objects, Comparator<ZipInfo> zipComp) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I have forgotten something like that! The compiler kept pointing to "ArrayList objects" for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set an identifier for your second parameter:

```
public class Sorts {
    public static void sort(ArrayList objects, Comparator<ZipInfo> comp) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the comparator argument name. You just specified type. So define it like:

```
public static void sort(ArrayList objects, Comparator<ZipInfo> comparator) {
```